# Localizar componente Delphi por string

Tags: delphi

Preciso abrir um form no *Delphi*, mas em vez de chamá-lo direto pelo nome `UniForm1`, preciso chamá-lo pelo valor armazenado numa *String*.

```
procedure TMainForm.UniTreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TUniTreeNode);
var nome : string;
    tela : TUniForm;
begin
   nome := Node.Text;
   tela := FindComponent(nome) as TUniForm;

   //UniPanel1.Caption := nome;

   tela.Parent := UniPanel1;
   tela.Show;
   tela.SetFocus;
end;
```

Porém, quando seleciono algum item no *TreeView*, acontece o seguinte erro e não abre o form:

> Project Log_Project.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message
>   'access violation at 0x006d0f13: read of adress 0x000003ce'.

Comment: O que estas a tentar fazer? A funçao FindComponent é do proprio form (TMainform). O form que queres procurar quase de certeza que não está nessa lista. Porque nao tens um dictionary com os forms e os seus nomes em string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como disse o @Tiago Rodrigues, o `form` que você esta procurando provavelmente não esta dentro desse outro `form`. Dentro de `Application` você tem essa mesma função `FindComponent`, pode utiliza-la para encontrar o seu `form`.

```
tela := Application.FindComponent(nome) as TUniForm;
```

Nesse ponto você não tem certeza se o `form` que você esta procurando foi encontrado, então o ideal é que você verifique se ele realmente foi encontrado antes de fazer alguma coisa com ele.

```
if (tela <> nil) then
  begin
    tela.Parent := UniPanel1;
    tela.Show;
    if (tela.Showing) then
      tela.SetFocus;
  end;
```

Só mais uma coisa, antes de dar um `SetFocus` em qualquer componente, verifique se o mesmo esta sendo exibido com a propriedade `Showing`. Se esta propriedade retornar `True`, significa que o componente esta sendo exibido, se retornar `False`, o componente não esta sendo exibido. Essa verificação é necessária, pois se o componente não estiver sendo exibido o programa irá lançar uma exceção.
Quando o componente não é um `form`, eu costumo também verificar se o `Enabled` dele também não esta `False`, para ai sim dar um `SetFocus`.

Comment: Desta vez, não deu erro, mas variável tela sempre está recebendo nil. Então o form nunca está sendo encontrado? O que devo fazer?

Comment: Como você cria esse formulário que você esta procurando?

Comment: Ele foi criado manualmente mesmo, durante o desenvolvimento do programa. Agora o que estou tentando fazer é exibir o nome de todos forms num TreeView, pra quando selecionar um nome, abri-lo no panel ao lado.

Comment: Mas os `forms` que você quer listar estão instanciados?
Coloquei essa `procedure` em um projeto meu que contém vários `forms` criados e instanciados assim que inicia o projeto e ele me mostrou todos:

`var
  i: integer;
  Forms: String;
begin
  Forms := '';
  for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if (Application.Components[i] is Tform) then
      Forms := Forms + TForm(Application.Components[i]).Name;
  ShowMessage(Forms);`

Comment: Copiei o código e após executá-lo, o ShowMessage mostrou apenas "ServerForm". O que isso quer dizer?

Comment: Significa que os outros `forms` não são filhos de `Application` ou eles não foram instanciados. Qual a versão do seu `Delphi`?

Comment: Delphi XE 10 Seattle

Comment: Então preciso fazer o que para resolver isso?

Comment: Vai no menu `Project` e clica em `Options`, selecione a sessão `Forms`, e verifique se os seus `Forms` estão em `Auto-create forms` ou em `Available forms`.

Comment: Estão todos em Available forms.

Comment: Então o seu `form` não existe quando você procura. Por esse motivo você não encontra. Antes de fazer essa pesquisa você precisa instanciar o seu formulário.

Comment: Como eu faço isso?

Comment: A saída mais fácil é você passar os formulários que você quer encontrar nessa varredura de `Available forms` para `Auto-create forms`.

Comment: Não deu certo... [dcc32 Error] Log_Project.dpr(20): E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter